# Populating treeview from XML

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, treenode

I am currently trying to populate a treeview from xml that is returned to me from a web request. When the response comes in I am manipulating the data so that the XML is in this layout:

```
<GroupList>
    <Group>
        <GroupName>my first test group</GroupName>
        <GroupID>djnsldgnljsdngljsdngljns</GroupID>
        <AccessLevel>high</AccessLevel>
        <SubGroup>
            <SubGroupName>my first test subgroup</SubGroupName>
            <SubGroupID>djnsldgnljsdngljsdngljns</SubGroupID>
        </SubGroup>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <GroupName>my second test group</GroupName>
        <GroupID>djnsldgnljsdngljsdngl</GroupID>
        <AccessLevel>high</AccessLevel>
        <SubGroup>
            <SubGroupName>my second test subgroup</SubGroupName>
            <SubGroupID>DBXRdjnsldgnljsdngljsdngl</SubGroupID>
        </SubGroup>
        <SubGroup>
            <SubGroupName>my second test subgroup1</SubGroupName>
            <SubGroupID>EJdjnsldgnljsdngljsdngl42</SubGroupID>
        </SubGroup>
    </Group>
</GroupList>
```

All I want to do is display the groupName and then you are able to expand and view the subgroups. Currently I have got it "sort of" working but its all in one linear view. Here is my code I currently have:

```
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(response2);

  groupsTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
  groupsTreeView.Nodes.Add(new
  TreeNode(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InnerText));
  TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
  tNode = (TreeNode)groupsTreeView.Nodes[0];

  addTreeNode(xmlDoc.DocumentElement, tNode);

  groupsTreeView.ExpandAll();

//This function is called recursively until all nodes are loaded
    private void addTreeNode(XmlNode xmlNode, TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        XmlNode xNode;
        TreeNode tNode;
        XmlNodeList xNodeList;
        if (xmlNode.HasChildNodes) //The current node has children
        {
            xNodeList = xmlNode.ChildNodes;

            for (int x = 0; x <= xNodeList.Count - 1; x++)
            //Loop through the child nodes
            {
                xNode = xmlNode.ChildNodes[x];
                groupsTreeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Value));
                tNode = groupsTreeView.Nodes[x];
                addTreeNode(xNode, tNode);
            }
        }
        else //No children, so add the outer xml (trimming off whitespace)
            treeNode.Text = xmlNode.OuterXml.Trim();
    }
```

This image is what the above code looks like when browsed on my system locally:

[image]

Any suggestions, im quite lost and it's doing my head in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using this using the linq xml(System.Xml.Linq):

```
    private TreeNode TNGroups(XElement xml)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        foreach (XElement group in xml.Descendants("Group"))
        {
            TreeNode tnGroup = new TreeNode(group.Element("GroupName").Value);
            node.Nodes.Add(tnGroup);
            foreach (XElement subgroup in group.Elements("SubGroup"))
            {
                TreeNode tnSubGroup = new TreeNode(subgroup.Element("SubGroupName").Value);
                tnGroup.Nodes.Add(tnSubGroup);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```

You would call it like this `myTreeView.Nodes.Add(TNGroups(groupsXML))`.

To load you XML into an element just use `XElement.Load`.

Comment: Would this be instead of my addTreeNode method or to replace all the above code?

Comment: Cheers buddy. I make a couple of small changes such as XElement.Parse and instead of node.Nodes.Add it's node.ChildNodes.Add Thanks for the answer though dude, helped me big time. Big +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar.  I liked the attribute addition in bferrer's answer so I modified it and put it in a class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeViewTest
{
    class XmlTreeViewBuilder
    {
        private XmlDocument xDoc;
        private TreeView tView;

        //Constructor with parameters
        public XmlTreeViewBuilder(XmlDocument xDocument, TreeView treeView)
        {
            this.xDoc = xDocument;
            this.tView = treeView;
        }

        public void getTreeView()
        {
            tView.Nodes.Clear();                                        //Clear out the nodes before building
            XmlNode pNode = xDoc.DocumentElement;                       //Set the xml parent node = xml document element
            string Key = pNode.Name == null ? "" : pNode.Name;          //If null set to empty string, else set to name
            string Value = pNode.Value == null ? Key : pNode.Value;     //If null set to node name, else set to value
            TreeNode tNode = tView.Nodes.Add(Key, Value);               //Add the node to the Treeview, set tNode to that node
            AddTreeNodes(pNode, tNode);                                 //Call the recursive function to build the tree
        }

        //Build out the tree recursively
        private void AddTreeNodes(XmlNode currentParentNode, TreeNode currentTreeNode)
        {
            //Check to see if the node has attributes, if so add them
            if (currentParentNode.Attributes != null && currentParentNode.Attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute attrib in currentParentNode.Attributes)
                {
                    //Create a node for the attribute name
                    TreeNode attribNode = new TreeNode();
                    attribNode.Name = attrib.Name;
                    attribNode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    attribNode.Text = "<Attribute>:" + attrib.Name;
                    //treeNode adds the attribute node
                    currentTreeNode.Nodes.Add(attribNode);

                    //Create a node for the attribute value
                    TreeNode attribValue = new TreeNode();
                    attribValue.Name = attrib.Name;
                    attribValue.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    attribValue.Text = attrib.Value;
                    //Attribute node adds the value node
                    attribNode.Nodes.Add(attribValue);
                }
            }
            //Recursively add children, grandchildren, etc...
            if (currentParentNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode childNode in currentParentNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    string Key = childNode.Name == null ? "" : childNode.Name;
                    string Value = childNode.Value == null ? Key : childNode.Value;
                    TreeNode treeNode = currentTreeNode.Nodes.Add(Key, Value);
                    //Recursive call to repeat the process for all child nodes which may be parents
                    AddTreeNodes(childNode, treeNode);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now from my form I simply have to instantiate an object and call the getTreeView() like so:

```
        XmlTreeViewBuilder tBuilder = new XmlTreeViewBuilder(xmlDoc, treeView1);
        tBuilder.getTreeView();
```

I can add more functions to the class as needed, such as: getNode, setNode, etc.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Dude, this is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly using recursion to move through the Xml file, unfortunately you are adding the Treenodes to the root of the Treeview on each iteration.  Instead, modify your code to add child nodes to the treenode being processed in your loop, e.g.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= xNodeList.Count - 1; x++)
    //Loop through the child nodes
    {
        xNode = xmlNode.ChildNodes[x];
        // Use the treenode, not the treeview!!!
        treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Value));
        tNode = groupsTreeView.Nodes[x];
        addTreeNode(xNode, tNode);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I cant do treeNode.Node because treeNode is of class TreeNode not Treeview. I have done 'treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Value));' Which seems to work better. I now have a route element of 'sam test group' which is correct as its my first group and it displays 4 empty check boxes then 'sam test group' as a sub-group. Also it doesn't read the second group element in the xml. Dam treeview, why does it make it so fiddly!

Answer (score 0):

I Used your answering codes, and got that some XML with Attributes and complex structures was missdisplayed. And mixing all your ideas got this. As if can be usefull for someone

```
   private void populateBaseNodes(XmlDocument docXML)
    {
        tView.Nodes.Clear(); // Clear
        tView.BeginUpdate();
        TreeNode treenode;

        XmlNodeList baseNodeList = docXML.ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in baseNodeList)
        {
            string key = xmlnode.Name == null ? "" : xmlnode.Name.ToString();
            string value = xmlnode.Value == null ? xmlnode.Name.ToString() : xmlnode.Value.ToString();
            treenode = tView.Nodes.Add(key, value); // add it to the tree

            if (xmlnode.Attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute att in xmlnode.Attributes)
                {
                    TreeNode tnode = new TreeNode();
                    string _name = att.Name;
                    string _value = att.Value.ToString();
                    tnode.Name= _name;
                    tnode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    tnode.Text= "<Attribute>:" +_name;
                    TreeNode _attvalue = new TreeNode();
                    _attvalue.Name = _name;
                    _attvalue.Text = _value;
                    _attvalue.ForeColor = Color.Purple;
                    tnode.Nodes.Add(_attvalue);
                    treenode.Nodes.Add(tnode);
                }
            }
            AddChildNodes(xmlnode, treenode);
        }
        tView.EndUpdate();
        tView.Refresh();
    }

    private void AddChildNodes(XmlNode nodeact, TreeNode TreeNodeAct)
    {
        XmlNodeList ChildNodeList = nodeact.ChildNodes;
        TreeNode aux = null;

        if (nodeact.HasChildNodes)
        {
            //Recursive Call
            foreach (XmlNode xmlChildnode in nodeact.ChildNodes)
            {
                //Add Actual Node & Properties
                string Key = xmlChildnode.Name == null ? "" : xmlChildnode.Name.ToString();
                string Value = xmlChildnode.Value == null ? xmlChildnode.Name.ToString() : xmlChildnode.Value.ToString();

                aux = TreeNodeAct.Nodes.Add(Key, Value);
                AddChildNodes(xmlChildnode, aux);

                if (xmlChildnode.Attributes != null && xmlChildnode.Attributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (XmlAttribute att in xmlChildnode.Attributes)
                    {
                        TreeNode tnode = new TreeNode();
                        string _name = att.Name;
                        string _value = att.Value.ToString();
                        tnode.Name = _name;
                        tnode.Text = "<Attribute>:" + _name;
                        tnode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        tnode.Text = "<Attribute>:" + _name;
                        TreeNode _attvalue = new TreeNode();
                        _attvalue.Name = _name;
                        _attvalue.Text = _value;
                        _attvalue.ForeColor = Color.Purple;
                        tnode.Nodes.Add(_attvalue);
                        aux.Nodes.Add(tnode);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }

    }
```